# Xamarin: Detect device rotation when orientation is locked? For iOS and/or Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms app that plays videos similar to a YouTube type app. I want the video to go full screen when the device rotates (like youtube does) but I also want the orientation to be locked in to portrait. Every post or tutorial I've found points to using  custom renders for detecting orientation change to determine when the device rotates, but when orientation is locked those events do not fire.

**Is there a way to detect device rotation without depending on orientation changing?**

Comment: You want to lock the orientation, but then change to Landscape when rotating the device?

Comment: Just the video part of the app, not the whole thing. If I press the full screen button on the video player I already have an animation programmed to make the video go full screen and "landscape" (view rotates 90 degrees). I want that same animation to run when the device is rotated but I don't want the whole app to go in landscape mode. Youtube does this really well somehow and I want to emulate that.

Answer (score 2):

On iOS you would get device orientation with:

```cs
var orientation = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Orientation;
```

On Android you need to ask the Window Manager:

```cs
var windowManager = ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();
var orientation = windowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation;
```

You don't need a custom renderer, but you could suffice with a service you register in the service locator. This could looks something like.

In shared code:

```cs
public enum Orientation
{
    None,
    PortraitUp,
    PortraitDown,
    LandscapeLeft,
    LandscapeRight
}

public interface IOrientationService
{
    Orientation GetCurrentOrientation();
}
```

On Android:

```cs
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AndroidOrientationService))]

public class AndroidOrientationService : IOrientationService
{
    private readonly IWindowManager _windowManager;
    public AndroidOrientationService()
    {
        _windowManager = ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();
    }

    public Orientation GetCurrentOrientation()
    {
        switch (_windowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation)
        {
            case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation0:
                return Orientation.PortraitUp;
            case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation180:
                return Orientation.PortraitDown;
            case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation90:
                return Orientation.LandscapeLeft;
            case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation270:
                return Orientation.LandscapeRight;
            default:
                return Orientation.None;   
        }
    }   
}
```

Similarly on iOS:

```cs
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(IosOrientationService))]

public class IosOrientationService : IOrientationService
{
    public Orientation GetCurrentOrientation()
    {
        switch (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Orientation)
        {
            case UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
                return Orientation.LandscapeLeft;
            case UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
                return Orientation.LandscapeRight;
            case UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait:
                return Orientation.PortraitUp;
            case UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown:
                return Orientation.PortraitDown;
            default:
                return Orientation.None;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your code you should be able to get the orientation like:

```cs
var orientationService = DependencyService.Get<IOrientationService>();
var orientation = orientationService.GetCurrentOrientation();
```

**EDIT**: detecting orientation changes

If you want to detect orientation changes on iOS you can do that by adding an observer for `UIDeviceOrientation`.

```cs
UIDevice.Notifications.ObserveOrientationDidChange(OnOrientationChanged);
```

Similarly on Android you can use `SensorManager` to listen to `SensorType.Orientation` changes. It has a bit more moving parts but looks something like follows.

You need to create a `ISensorEventListener` class:

```cs
class MyOrientationListner : Java.Lang.Object, ISensorEventListener
{
    public event EventHandler OrientationChanged;

    public void OnAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, SensorStatus accuracy)
    {
    }

    public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
    {
        OrientationChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);    
    }
}
```

Then you need to get the sensor manager from the current `Context` and start listening to orientation change events:

```cs
_sensorManager = context.GetSystemService(Context.SensorService).JavaCast<SensorManager>();
var sensor = _sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Orientation);
var listener = new MyOrientationListner();
listener.OrientationChanged += OnOrientationChanged;
_sensorManager.RegisterListener(listener, sensor, SensorDelay.Normal);

private void OnOrientationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OrientationChanged?.Invoke(this, GetCurrentOrientation());
}
```

Where `OrientationChanged` is a event in the `IOrientationService`:

```cs
event EventHandler<Orientation> OrientationChanged;
```

Then you can listen to that event where needed.

Comment: I'm aware of how to check and set orientation. My question was more along the lines of "Can I detect rotation without checking orientation since my orientation is purposefully locked into portrait?"

Comment: I've elaborated my answer

Answer (score 0):

For **iOS**
In **AppDelegate.cs** override the below method

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application,UIWindow forWindow)
    {
        if (Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current == null || Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage == null)
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
        }

        var mainPage = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage;

        if (mainPage is YourPage || (mainPage is NavigationPage &&
                                                 ((NavigationPage)mainPage).CurrentPage is YourPage) || (mainPage.Navigation != null &&
        mainPage.Navigation.ModalStack.LastOrDefault() is YourPage))
        {
            if (Configuration.IsFullScreen)
            {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape;
            }
        }
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
    }
```

In a **Dependency Service** write the below method

```
 public void ChangeLandscapeOrientation()
 {
     UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft), new NSString("orientation"));
     UINavigationController.AttemptRotationToDeviceOrientation();
 }
```

Call the **ChangeLandscapeOrientation** method wherever you need it.

For **Android**
In a **Dependency Service** write the below method to change the orientation to Landscape

```
public void ChangeLandscapeOrientation()
{
    var activity = (Activity)Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context;
    {
        activity.RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
        var attrs = activity.Window.Attributes;
        _originalFlags = attrs.Flags;
        attrs.Flags |= Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen;
        activity.Window.Attributes = attrs;
    }
}
```

Below code to change the orientation to Portrait

```
public void ChangePortraitOrientation()
{
    var activity = (Activity)Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context;
    {
        activity.RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
        var attrs = activity.Window.Attributes;
        attrs.Flags = _originalFlags;
        activity.Window.Attributes = attrs;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!